# vsftp error: 500 OOPS: child died

Tags: linux, ftp, chroot, vsftpd

I installed vsftp, and then setup the config file as following:

```
anonymous_enable=NO

local_enable=YES

write_enable=YES

local_umask=022

chroot_local_user=NO

chroot_list_enable=YES

chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list

xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log

anon_root=/var/ftp

local_root=~
```

and in /etc/vsftpd.chroot_list, I added the users that I allow to log in.

and then restart service:

`service vsftpd restart`

then when I try to log in, I got this error:

`ftp> open 127.0.0.1`

> Connected to 127.0.0.1.
>   500 OOPS: child died

I googled, but failed to find the answer.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: What is your OS ?

Comment: ubuntu 13.10, using linode VPS.

Comment: Can you try adding `seccomp_sandbox=NO` in your `vsftpd.conf` ?

Comment: that works! Magic. Thanks very much! This problem bothers me for quite a long time. So, could you tell me what is this directive doing and why none of the tutorials I saw mention it?

Comment: great! i've made an answer for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Unbuntu 13.10, some has reported this error and have fixed it by adding :

`seccomp_sandbox=NO` in `vsftpd.conf`

It seems this is because :

> With version 3.0 of vsftpd, a new feature was introduced and it
>   appears that this has caused problems for a few people. That feature
>   is seccomp sandboxing and it can turned off

Further infos :

- http://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2013/12/18/fixing-the-vsftpd-500-child-died-error-in-xubuntu-13-10/
- http://technologytales.com/2013/09/21/turning-off-seccomp-sandbox-in-vsftpd/

Comment: It also works in alpine linux